# How can I make ReSharper not add all my .Bind statements to the one line?

Tags: c#, resharper

I've looked through the options and I am still unable to find out why it's doing this. Here is the before:

```
var textLabel  = new TextLabel()
    .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Text1), source: this);
```

and here is the after:

```
var textLabel  = new TextLabel().Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Text1), source: this);
```

I would like it not to add them all to the same line but cannot find out how to disable this change.

Does anyone with some good knowledge of ReSharper no how I can stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this.  I need to change the following:

```
C# > Formatting Style > 
    Line Breaks and wrapping > 
    Arrangement of Method signatures > 
    Wrap formal parameters > 
    Chop always
```